# How to improve query speed to SQL Server extension in VS Code

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code and am running a SQL query that returns in a time of ~68 seconds.

When I run the same query using SQL Server, it takes ~11 seconds.

What can I do to speed up the time doing the same thing in VS Code?

Here is what I use in VS Code:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

server = 'server'
database = 'databse'
driver = 'driver'
database_con = f'mssql://@{server}/{database}?driver={driver}'

engine = create_engine(database_con)
con = engine.connect()

t = pd.Timestamp.now()
query = """
select top 1000 c.* from table a
join table2 b on a.number=b.number
join tabl3 c on b.id=c.id
where c.[column] = 59 and a.[Date] > '2023-01-01'
"""

data = pd.read_sql_query(query, con)
query_time = pd.Timestamp.now() - t
print(query_time)
```

Is this because of Python? I am concerned that if I run a query that takes ~10 minutes on SQL Server, it would take ~1 hour if I run in Python/VS Code, thereby negating benefits gained from what I can perform in python, vs writing a stored procedure in SQL Server to process, and then export the data, and run some python scripts on the data.

Reason for current flow (run everything in python) is that the results are time dependent, while running in a SQL Server stored procedure the time cannot be guaranteed to be ready at a specific time based on business needs

Comment: typo in the query? `join table2 on b on a.number=b.number` there's twice `on`

Comment: Some [required reading](https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: You probably need better indexing. How about you show us the tables and index definitions, and share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. We can't really help otherwise.

Comment: How does the query even execute? T-SQL doesn't particularly like having entire statements surrounded with `[ ... ]`. Square brackets are only meant to go around identifiers.

Comment: @alwayslearning he probably missed something when anonymising the secret algorithm on how to beat the stock market

Comment: I don't get this bit _while running in a SQL Server stored procedure the time cannot be guaranteed to be ready at a specific time based on business needs_  I guess you first need to be sure that the piece you are doing in python can only be done in Python (and not in SQL). Also _When I run the same query using SQL Server, it takes ~11 seconds._ Are you saying when you run it in SQl Server Management Studio, while you are logged on locally to the SQL Server? Is the Python code also running locally on the SQL Server? Please be specific as there are many factors to consider here